# Windows stuck on "Welcome" screen specifically after disconnect + reconnecting to RemoteApp

Tags: windows-server-2019, remote-desktop-services, remoteapp

I have been intermittently working on an issue for weeks now and I can't seem to find the solution.

We have a legacy MS Access desktop application on an Azure VM that we stream to the users as a MS RemoteApp. They login through a shortcut on their desktop (or through RD Web Access, doesn't seem to make a difference).

It often happens, if they close the RemoteApp and then try to open it again shortly after, that the application refuses to load. The MSTSC window just keeps hanging and when I click the "expand" button to show what's actually happening, I see the user is stuck on some Windows "Welcome" screen.

Nothing helps except logging into the server as admin and manually logging off the user. The only processes open at that time are the Access executable (but I can kill that manually, and still the session hangs) and some Windows processes (see screenshot). Does anybody have a clue how I can avoid this hanging session issue?

Running processes for the user that are stuck on the welcome screen

The server is a Windows Server 2019 Datacenter with all updates installed until today.

The issue is **specifically **bound to connections right after closing the previous connection.

I already

- Messed around with server configuration (GPO and other settings), no results
- Deployed an extra RemoteApp that starts logoff.exe manually on the server (doesn't get through the Welcome screen either)
- Killed mstsc.exe locally
- Googled a lot
- ...

but without much result... I'm hoping someone here has had the same problem.

Comment: We are currently experiencing this issues with a citrix VDI, did you ever find a solution?